# SOAP Call from iOS to PHP Script

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, soap

I am currently building a simple iOS that that calls a php page on my server called "SoapTest.php". I currently have a test function that takes in a variable called "$x". I am sending a request to this function and it can take one variable. But where I am running into the issue is having the function taking in more then one variable or sending back one or more variables.

I understand that this PHP function will only work with one variable ($x), but how do it get it work with multiple variables.

Here is my PHP function:

```
function test($x)
{
  return $x;
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to add varaibles to the function do this:

```
function test($x, $y, $z)
{
  /*Do stuff here*/
  return $x;
{
```

This will accept 3 variables, `$x`, `$y`, `$z`. You'll then have access to all 3